# Blazor Virtualize component and broken scrolling when dragging scrollbar

Tags: c#, blazor, ui-virtualization

I have a custom datagrid with row vitrualization.

When I scroll down by dragging the scrollbar, the scrolling is interrupted as before new "page" is rendered.

[image: screen recording]

Do you have any idea, why this might be happening?

```
<div class="sg-container" style="height:200px">
    <div class="simple-grid" style="grid-template-columns: 3em minmax(5em, auto); ">
        <Virtualize Items="_products" 
                    ItemSize="32">
            <ItemContent>
                <div class="sg-row sg-row ">
                    <div class="sg-cell ">@context.Id</div>
                    <div class="sg-cell ">@context.Name</div>
                </div>
            </ItemContent>
        </Virtualize>

    </div>
</div>
```

Demo (REPL) is here: https://blazorrepl.com/repl/mvkBuHuB22FVBxY258

Comment: What is your `OverscanCount` set to? It seems to me that you are not letting it load a sufficient amount of items outside the view area. The next piece to look at will be your `ItemsProvider` logic, can you update with that?

Comment: If OverscanCount is too low, there would be placeholders, and they are there. The scrolling is broken also with Items bound to an array, so it' probably not broken by ItemsProvider

Comment: Sure, however I successfully load 100s to 1000s of items into a `<tbody />` without any flickering, scroll issues, or missing entries using an items `ICollection` without the provider. What happens if you recreate this using an extremely more simplified implementation?

Comment: Im not using a `<table>` element. See my repl for the simplest demo of the bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory they should have fixed this bug according to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26870). Your scenario may be different, so maybe it's worth filing a bug, because this definitely smells like a Blazor bug to me.

Comment: was this an answer or was this an input?

Comment: This could probably be a comment. On the other hand, the question is *"Do you have any idea, why this might be happening?"*, and this technically answers that.